# HTML. How to pass check box value to php?

Tags: php, html, post, checkbox, get

I have form and here is check box, how to pass value from check box to PHP? For example.: If checkbox is checked  pass `1`, if not checked `0`.

I'm using following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="letter" value="letter" id="letter" checked="checked">
```

This is my form:

```
  <form class="form"  method="post" action="GetFbId.php">
    <h2>Registration</h2><hr/>
    <label>First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" required>

    <label>Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" required>

    <label>City: </label>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" required>

    <label>Email: </label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required><br>

    Accept to get letters 
    <input type="checkbox" name="letter" value="letter" id="letter" checked="checked">

    <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$_POST['letter']` will be set if, and only if, the checkbox was checked during the form submission.

Just test like so:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['letter']))
{
    // $_POST['letter'] is set, checkbox has been checked.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In PHP, checkbox inputs will either be set in the `$_POST` array, or they won't be. Checked checkboxes will be set, unchecked checkboxes will not.

If you change the value of the checkbox to 1 so that `$_POST['letter']` would be `1`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="letter" value="1" id="letter">
```

Then, if you need a 0 saved into the `$letter` variable if it's not checked,

```
$letter = isset($_POST['letter']) ? $_POST['letter'] : 0;
```

Another option is to do it on the front end where you save a value of 0 or 1 into a hidden input and check the value of `$_POST['letter']` on the PHP side because it will always have a value

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="letter" id="letter">
<input type="checkbox" name="select_letter" value="1" id="select_letter"
     onchange="document.getElementById('letter').value = this.checked ? 1 : 0">
```

Answer (score 3):

When check box is checked after submitting the form we can get the check box value in php

```
 <form class="form"  method="post" action="GetFbId.php">
<h2>Registration</h2><hr/>
<label>First Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" required>

<label>Last Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" required>

<label>City: </label>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" required>

<label>Email: </label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" required><br>

Accept to get letters 
<input type="checkbox" name="letter" value="letter" id="letter" checked="checked">

<input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register">
```

get check box value in GetFbId.php after submitting the form

```
<?php

//get post value
if(isset($_POST['letter']))
{
    echo $letter =  $_POST['letter']; //get check box value
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try something like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['letter']) && $_REQUEST['letter']=="letter"){
       $letter = $_POST['letter']; // check box value
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use like this

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
   // other code
   $checkboxval= $_POST['letter']; //if checked 1 if not 0
}        
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['letter'])){
   $letter = true;
}else{
   $letter = false;
}
```

?>

Is this what you are asking for?